# USB Drives and the Windows Drive Limit

Tags: windows, usb-drive

What happens on a Windows box once you add more drives than can fit in the A-Z drive letters. I know about the mountvol command but my solution needs to work on Win98/XP systems that do not use NTFS. Is there any way to provide access to those drives?

Comment: Isn´t this a "misdesign" issue? I mean, what could you possible need that many drive letters for?

Comment: Good question, the solution actually is supposed to allow you to attach ALL your flash/SD media and allow you to view their contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is physical drives that you have too many of you could consider a hardware solution (RAID) to combine multiple physical drives into less logical drives. This solution should work in Win98.

If it is mapped drives to Windows servers, consider using junction points on the server to combine multiple drives in to a single tree structure.

Or use DFS links; replication does not have to be turned on. This would create a logical hierarchy across multiple servers and you could map one drive letter to the DFS root.